# Zabbix Web Scenario / 400

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am struggling with Zabbix Web Scenarios, I am trying to post to a url in the same way this curl does:

```
 curl -XPOST xxxx -d' { "grant_type": "password", "username": "xxx", "password": "xxx", "client_id": "xxx", "client_secret": "xxx"}'
```

However, I get a 400 error when loading it into Web Scenarios, here is the setup I am using in Zabbix.

[image: Zabbix Web Scenario]

This for some reason gives me back a 400 error, whereas the above curl works fine and I get an authorisation. Does any one have any more experience with this that can offer a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not posting a JSON, but a list of individual variables. Try using the JSON as-is.

Comment: Exactly that, I posted the following:

"grant_type": "xxx", "username": "xxx", "password": "xxx", "client_id": "xxx", "client_secret": "xxx" and it worked fine.

Thank you.

Comment: I think I clicked accept to early, it seems to saying 400 once again.

Comment: Are you missing the outer curly braces there?

Comment: I went back and added these 5 minutes ago and it was working but I wanted to wait a bit longer to be 100% Sure :P You are awesome, thank you.